# Update specific user FOSuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, web, fosuserbundle

i am working on a site web with symfony and in the part of dashboard admin i like that the admin can change the users profile so that for example change username or password

i am using FOSuserbundleand also table "fos_user" so how i can change users information ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853676/best-step-by-step-tutorial-for-symfony-i-am-running-php-on-windows, also note the reasons why that question was closed.  You may need to be a little more specific about what you have tried and where you are stuck

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and the errors you get with your attempts. Please also read this page to learn how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't forget the mark the right answer! Seems to me the problem is solved!

Comment: @TimOgilvy its my first question here :)

Comment: @RenatoMendesFigueiredo done thx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should work with the [`fos_user.user_manager`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html) service.

In your controller, retrieve the user from the datastore with

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('id'=> $id)); // get user by id
// or
$user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($username); // get user by username
```

then you can change what you want, example:

```
$user->setEmail('new_email@foo.com');
$user->setPlainPassword('new_password');
```

Finally, you can update the data with

```
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

Comment: it work even if i will update the username and finduserbyusername too?

Comment: you can change the username, yes.